# Doob's first martingale convergence theorem

Tags: limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

This theorem states that, if $(M_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a supermartingale with $\sup_n E[M_n^-]<\infty$, then, almost surely, there exists $M_{\infty}:=\lim_n M_n$ and $|M_{\infty}|<\infty$.

My question is how we know that $M_{\infty}$ is a random variable, that is, measurable. Do we need the underlying probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ to be complete?

For instance, if I define $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ with $Y=\limsup_n M_n$, then $Y$ is indeed measurable and $Y=M_{\infty}$ almost surely. So we have a measurable "version" of $M_{\infty}$, right?

Comment: Pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable.

Comment: @Calculon Only in a [complete measure space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure) (in a space satisfying that subsets of null sets are measurable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. More precisely, defining the random variable $Y$ as you have, it is then true that $Y(\omega)=\lim_nM_n(\omega)$ for almost every $\omega\in\Omega$. $M_\infty$ is not unambiguously defined, because the convergence of $M_n$ is only almost sure.

Comment: So, when one says that the pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable, actually it means that there exists a "version" of the limit that is measurable, right?

Comment: If by "pointwise limit" you mean $f(x)=\lim_nf_n(x)$ for *all* $x$, then $f$ is measurable provided each $f_n$ is measurable. If you mean that there is a measurable set $N$ of measure $0$ with $f(x)=\lim_nf_n(x)$ for all $x\notin N$, then there is a question of how $f$ is to be defined on $N$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant your second type of limit: $f(x)=\lim_n f_n(x)$ for all $x\notin N$. Can you always find a version $g$ of $f$ (I mean, $g$ such that $g=f$ almost surely) such that $g$ is measurable? I think yes, as one can define $g(x)=\limsup_n f_n(x)$ for every $x$, which is measurable and $g=f$ almost surely. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @user39756 That's only correct, if the measurable space is complete. And the ability to make your conclusion from $g=f$ a.s. is one of the main reasons why one cares about completing a measurable space.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: If there is, as I assumed, a measurable set $N$ with measure $0$ such that $f(x)=\lim_nf_n(x)$ exists for all $x\notin N$, and if $h:N\to\overline{\Bbb R}$ is measurable, then $g$ defined to equal $f$ on $N^c$ and to equal $h$ on $N$ is measurable (with values in $\overline{\Bbb R}$)  and $\lim_n f_n=g$ a.e. The specific choice $g(x):=\limsup_n f_n(x)$ is a special case. Completeness ensures that the choice of $g$ on $N$ is not important: If $g=\lim_n f_n$ a.e., then $g$ is necessarily measurable, provided the measurable space is complete.